# Appending text from gridview and sort them

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written the code in ASP.NET application like

```
  protected void chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkbox = sender as CheckBox;
        GridViewRow currentRow = chkbox.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        Label lblJurisdiction = grdView.Rows[currentRow.RowIndex].FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
        RequiredFieldValidator rfv = grdView.Rows[currentRow.RowIndex].FindControl("ValReqED") as RequiredFieldValidator;
        RequiredFieldValidator rfvExpD = grdView.Rows[currentRow.RowIndex].FindControl("ValReqExpD") as RequiredFieldValidator;
        RequiredFieldValidator rfvLN = grdView.Rows[currentRow.RowIndex].FindControl("ValReqLN") as RequiredFieldValidator;
        if (!chkbox.Checked)
        {
            rfv.Enabled = false;
            rfvExpD.Enabled = false;
            rfvLN.Enabled = false;
            string JurisdictionRemoved = lblJurisdiction.Text + ",";
            string Jurisdiction = txtJurisdiction.Text;
            string ReplacedJurisdiction = Jurisdiction.Replace(JurisdictionRemoved, "");
            txtJurisdiction.Text = ReplacedJurisdiction;
        }
        else
        {
            string Jurisdiction = txtJurisdiction.Text;
            txtJurisdiction.Text = Jurisdiction + "," + lblJurisdiction.Text.ToString(); 
        }
    }
```

Note that string Jurisdictions contains set of Jurisdictions like

```
     Delaware,Georgia,Illinois,Kansas,Maine
```

And string JurisdictionRemoved contains only one jurisdiction like (where user will uncheck the checkbox)

```
   Georgia
```

Then txtJurisdicton must contain

```
     Delaware,Illinois,Kansas,Maine
```

if string JurisdictionRemoved contains "Maine" then above code doesnot works, it is not removed.

Now I want that whenever user will uncheck the checkbox that Jurisdiction should be removed from txtJurisdiction textbox and whenever user will check the checkbox the corresponding jurisdiction should be appended to the txtJurisdiction. Let us suppose that user has checked "Georgia" again
then the textbox should contain

```
       Delaware,Georgia,Illinois,Kansas,Maine
```

The above code doesn't work like this. Also I want it append checked jurisdiction in the textbox alphabetically and should eliminate the redundant state. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this issue you can do like this

1. split conman separated list to an array using `split` function
2. Remove the text from the array using condition
3. User `String.Join` method to create new string.
4. Assign that value to your textbox.

Example

```
List<String> Items = Jurisdiction.Split(",");
Items.Remove( lblJurisdiction.Text);
string NewX = String.Join(",", Items.ToArray());
```